# Change certain matrix entry with probability

Tags: matrix

I really appreciate some help in this problem:
Now I have a diagonal matrix A with only 0 and 1 and its diagonal entries are all 0.
From first row onwards, for each row I hope to change 1 into 0 with probability p (probability that this 1 is changed into 0 is p). I tried:
ReplacePart[A,RandomSample[Position[A[[1]],1],p*Length[A]]—>0]
But it seems Position doesn’t recognize row of matrix. I wonder if there is any other command can be used or any correction suggested. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

We first create a diagonal matrix with 0 and 1:

```
n = 4;
mat = DiagonalMatrix[Table[ RandomInteger[{0, 1}], n]]
```

Then we change the 1's with probability p to zero:

```
p = 1/2;
Do[mat[[i, i]] = RandomChoice[{p, 1 - p} -> {0, mat[[i, i]]}], {i, n}];
mat
```